# systemd: Timeout for ExecStartPre

Tags: systemd

I am working with a systemd service file with a long-running `ExecStartPre`. (If you must know, it is an `aws route53 wait resource-record-sets-changed` that runs for a while) and the timeout seems to be 90 seconds. Setting `TimeoutSec` does not seem to change this.

How do I change the timeout?

```
# systemctl --version
systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.6)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found my own answer. TL;DR. Its `TimeoutSec=15min` not `TimeoutSec="15min"` Along the way, the `systemd-analyze dump` command was helpful. Verbose, but highlighted that `TimeoutStartSec` and `TimeoutStopSec` were still set to their default values of 90 seconds.

Comment: Try `systemctl show <unit>` to debug the current settings.